# Find when a specific char is 2nd to last in a string in pig

Tags: apache-pig, case

I have the following data:

```
address|some_mask_value
123 Main | 10100011110
124 Main | 10100011100
```

I am using Apache Pig version 0.15.0.2.4.2.0-258

I'm trying to create an indicator where the 2nd to last character in 'some_mask_value' is a 1.  I've tried:

```
load_data = LOAD '/myfile.txt' USING PigStorage('|') AS (address:String, some_mask_value:String);

grunt> case_test = FOREACH load_data GENERATE (CASE trial
>> WHEN LAST_INDEX_OF(name, '1') 2 THEN yes
>> ELSE no);

2017-04-20 16:59:50,522 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 5, column 30>  mismatched input '2' expecting THEN
```

Basically, if the 2nd to last character is 1, then I'll filter out that row later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = load 'data.txt' using PigStorage('|') 
       as (address: chararray, some_mask_value:chararray);
```

If mask field is fixed length, like in you sample data, then:

```
b = foreach a generate $0 .. , (
        CASE SUBSTRING(some_mask_value, 9, 10)
            WHEN '1' THEN 'YES'
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) as inidcator;

dump b;
(123 Main,10100011110,YES)
(124 Main,10100011100,NO)
```

if mask is not fixed length:

```
b = foreach a generate $0 .. , (
        CASE SUBSTRING(some_mask_value, (int)SIZE(some_mask_value) - 2, (int)SIZE(some_mask_value) - 1)
            WHEN '1' THEN 'YES'
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    ) as indicator;
dump b;
(123 Main,10100011110,YES)
(124 Main,10100011100,NO)
```

This assumes mask field dost not have leading or trailing spaces.